# How do I get back to my index page?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I start off at the index page, when I click sign up, the form comes back as expected, but when I click the submit (signup) button, the values get stored into the database but I get redirected to the wrong page. How do I get back to the initial index page?

Php code for redirection:

```
<?php
     $query = "INSERT INTO details (username, password, email) 
               VALUES('$username', '$pass', '$email')";
     mysqli_query($database, $query);
     echo "<script>window.open(''index.php','_self')</script>";
     $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
     $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
 ?>
```

I want to get back to https://MYIPADDRESS/Admin_area/index.php when I submit the form. Thank you in advance

Comment: what's not working for you here; and are you checking for errors? You seem to want us to debug this for you.

Comment: this piece of code will have you gawking one day, when your db's been compromised. What are you waiting for to use a prepared statement and a safe hashing method for passwords? when it's too late?

Comment: Everything is working, but the echo statement is incorrect, I want to get back to the URL at the end of the question, but instead get directed to my signup file sign_up.php instead of Admin_area/index.php

Comment: check for errors then using php's error reporting and proper error handling on the query.

Comment: `echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";` you have extra quote `'` i suppose that you already stat the session using `session_start();` on top of php.

Comment: You're not starting the session on that block of code so your sessions arn't getting set.

Comment: You should probably use [the PHP header function](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_header.asp) to redirect when you are using PHP code.  Try using `header('Location: index.php');` in place of your echo.

Answer (score 3):

Replace

`$_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";`

with

`header('Location: https://yourWebsite.com/');`

And it will redirect users to whatever page you specified.

You can read more about PHP `header()` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).

EDIT: Do also read about [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [password hashing](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) because the script you're using right now is vunerable to SQL injections.